# Jquery Animation slideUp don't work because it is instantly up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

When my div is shown and I click on the close button the div needs to slideUp but the animation isn't working because it is instantly get up... Could someone tell me how I can get the animation to work?

```
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
        $('#voteFormContainer').slideUp(200, function(){
          $('#voteFormContainer').removeClass('scaleToOne');
          $('.menu--under').slideUp(300);
        });
        $('body').removeClass('body-scroll-block');
      });

      $('.voteButton').on('click', function() {
        $('#voteFormContainer').css('display', 'block');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#voteFormContainer').addClass('scaleToOne');
        },10);
        $('.menu--under').slideDown(300);
        $('body').addClass('body-scroll-block');
      });


    #voteFormContainer {
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve